# Mysql Compare two datetime fields

Tags: mysql, datetime, compare, field

I want to compare two dates with time, I want all the results `from tbl where date1 > date2`

```
Select * From temp where mydate > '2009-06-29 04:00:44';
```

but it is just comparing dates not time. it is giving me all the result set of today's date

```
'2009-06-29 11:08:57'
'2009-06-29 11:14:35'
'2009-06-29 11:12:38'
'2009-06-29 11:37:48'
'2009-06-29 11:52:17'
'2009-06-29 12:12:50'
'2009-06-29 12:13:38'
'2009-06-29 12:19:24'
'2009-06-29 12:27:25'
'2009-06-29 12:28:49'
'2009-06-29 12:35:54'
'2009-06-29 12:36:54'
'2009-06-29 12:49:57'
'2009-06-29 12:58:04'
'2009-06-29 04:13:20'
'2009-06-29 04:56:19'
'2009-06-29 05:00:23'
'2009-06-29 05:04:26'
'2009-06-29 05:08:17'
'2009-06-29 05:26:57'
'2009-06-29 05:29:06'
'2009-06-29 05:32:11'
'2009-06-29 05:52:07'
```

Comment: There's no result there that's less than '2009-06-29 04:00:44';, so it seems your code is working, or am I missing something?

Comment: I want these dates as Output not before that
'2009-06-29 04:56:19'
'2009-06-29 05:00:23'
'2009-06-29 05:04:26'
'2009-06-29 05:08:17'
'2009-06-29 05:26:57'
'2009-06-29 05:29:06'
'2009-06-29 05:32:11'
'2009-06-29 05:52:07'

Comment: Um... You don't have any visible from before that. It seems you're suggesting '2009-06-29 11:08:57' comes before '2009-06-29 04:00:44'. 4AM comes before 11am, and therefore you're  seeing that 11am is greater than 4am. Again, am I missing something?

Comment: 2009-06-29 04:00:44' this is 4PM, so i dont want 11AM records. can i get them

Comment: Nope! 4pm is 16:00:00 :) 4am is 04:00:00.

Comment: You column is of the right type, right?

Comment: Thanks my clock was 12 hour clock so i was getting that resultset. :P
Thanks again

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The query you want to show as an example is:

```
SELECT * FROM temp WHERE mydate > '2009-06-29 16:00:44';
```

04:00:00 is 4AM, so all the results you're displaying come *after* that, which is correct.

If you want to show everything after 4PM, you need to use the correct (24hr) notation in your query.

To make things a bit clearer, try this:

```
SELECT mydate, DATE_FORMAT(mydate, '%r') FROM temp;
```

That will show you the date, and its 12hr time.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the following SQL to compare both date and time -

```
Select * From temp where mydate > STR_TO_DATE('2009-06-29 04:00:44', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

Attached mysql output when I used same SQL on same kind of table and field that you mentioned in the problem-

[image]

It should work perfect.

Comment: Brilliant. Mysql is comparing string instead of dates!
I'll keep this in mind from now on.

Great answer, upvoted!

Answer (score 7):

Your query apparently returned all correct dates, even considering the time.

If you're still not happy with the results, give DATEDIFF a shot and look for negaive/positive results between the two dates.

Make sure your `mydate` column is a `datetime` type.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to order it?

```
Select * From temp where mydate > '2009-06-29 04:00:44' ORDER BY mydate;
```

Comment: no i m getting all the result set for todays date not after the datetime i have specified  for ex:- the time i have given is 4PM and i am getting 11AM records in that.

Comment: The time you've given is 4am.

Comment: Try

'Select * From temp where mydate > '2009-06-29 16:00:44';'