# how to do date comparision through sql query?

Tags: android, database

how to compare dates .

for example my date format is 2011/10/12(YYYY/MM/DD).

I'm having some date records in database .i want some record greater than particular date.

for example :

```
String compareDate=2011/10/16;

select * from testtable where date>compareDate;
```

how to get least date and highest date through database query.
in sqlite is there any method to compare dates.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: in which format and type date was stored into the table?

Comment: same format YYYY/MM/DD and date field type is text

Answer (score 1):

Push the date to query in right format

```
select * from testtable where date > '2011-10-16';
```

more

- [Mysql Compare two datetime fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058031/mysql-compare-two-datetime-fields)
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-date.html
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Date-Time/Comparedateinwhereclause.htm

Comment: i have created date field has text and compared date has string how to compare because in sqlite there is no date field name

Answer (score 0):

Before going to execute query, compareDate should be in this (`"yyyy-MM-dd")` format,

then try this query

```
select date from testtable where date > 'compareDate' order by date desc;
```

the above query order the date by descending order. The first row of cursor will have the max date.