# compare timestamps in mysql

Tags: mysql

I save timestamps in my database in this format 2012-04-16 08:58:55. I read a timestamp of my database and then i want to use this timestamp in another query and ask from the database to return records where the timestamp is greater equal than  this timestamp. I am using the ">=" but it is not working.

I am trying this one:

```
$query="SELECT DISTINCT timestamp,text FROM array WHERE id='$theID' AND timestamp>='$thisTimestamp'";
```

Comment: Can you show us what you're trying?

Comment: When you say that you are storing timestamps in the format *2012-04-16 08:58:55*, is that as a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Please provide a sample of $thisTimestamp

Comment: Please clarify "not working". Does the statement result in an error? Does it return the wrong data? Something else?

Comment: It returns wrong data. I have results from the query but not the results i want. I get the $thisTimestamp from the database also. When i print it i get something in this format 2012-04-16 08:58:55.

Comment: see MySQL [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Comment: or see [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does "not working" mean? It's not clear whether you want to compare datetime stamps or simply the time porition.

For the former, check this thread [Mysql Compare two datetime fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058031/mysql-compare-two-datetime-fields), for the latter, simply use the [TIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function in your query e.g. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE TIME(datetime) >= '08:58:55';`

Clarify your question if you are in search of something else.

EDIT: Have you not read my first link? That is exactly what you need given the problem you have provided so far. What **results** are you looking for? Give an example and then give an example of how your query is performing incorrectly. Without this information, no one will be able to give you complete help!