# Compare two dates in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code here which permits me to retrieve some dates.
I have a today date conserved in this way:

```
$time = date("d-m-Y");
```

My date field in the database is a varchar and it's in this format: d-m-Y

How can i compare them? i've used this but it won't work!

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('date','%d-%m-%Y'), id, WHERE date>$time;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's what you get when you store a **DATE** as a **VARCHAR**... Be smart, recreate the column to a `Date` type.

Comment: Yes, it would mean changing a lot of things then... :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651985/compare-dates-in-mysql

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058031/mysql-compare-two-datetime-fields

Comment: @Tao So? Your DB design is obviously flawed and that simply needs to be fixed. Or you'll keep bumping into things where you need weird, complicated solutions for something that would normally be a very easy thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compare date by fetching from database then I will suggest you to store in date format not in varchar format.

But now you can do following :

First use strtotime to convert your string to a unix timestamp. Like :

> ```
> $time = strtotime( $date );
> ```

Then you use this timestamp to calculate a date in whatever format you want. To get your desired format you can do like :

> ```
> $newDate = date( 'd-m-y', $time );
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function in the query to first convert the `VARCHAR` to a `DATETIME` value.

Answer (score 0):

You are building your WHERE-Clause with the original value, try something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('date','%d-%m-%Y') AS compare_date, `id` FROM `table_name` WHERE DATE_FORMAT('date','%d-%m-%Y') > $time;
```

Be aware that this is a string-comparison, so it would be best to do it the other way round, e.g. `%Y-%m-%d`

Or use the `STR_TO_DATE` function as @Micah Carrick suggested.

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra `,` after `id` and you need a `from` clause as well, in the query.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('date','%d-%m-%Y') as new_date, id from your_table WHERE new_date > $time;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      This Example Is Working 100% try Now

      $exp_date = "2006-01-16"; 

      $todays_date = date("Y-m-d"); 

      $today = strtotime($todays_date); 

      $expiration_date = strtotime($exp_date); 

      if ($expiration_date > $today) 
         { 
           $valid = "yes"; 
         } 
      else 
         { 
           $valid = "no"; 
         }
```