# Datetime datatype always ignores time in comparison

Tags: php, mysql

```
Select * from table where Startdatetime<='".$currentdatetime."' AND '".$currentdatetime."'<=t.Enddatetime
```

`$currentdatetime` is my variable containing the current date and time in 'Y-m-d H:i:s' format.

My problem is that MySQL is checking the date part properly, but the time is not considered in the check. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058031/mysql-compare-two-datetime-fields

Comment: i used 24 hrs clock, i also tried above link method but not working.if a deal startdatetime is (2014-11-12 23:00:00) and enddatetime is (2014-11-13 03:00:00) it should be visible when i enter current time 01:30:00 or else , but it is not happening. just  in comparison the time part is not working

Comment: change format to time stamp

Comment: Are you sure that `Startdatetime` is actually a DATETIME column?

Comment: yes it is a datetime datatype column

Answer (score 0):

Force the variable date time values to match the mysql datetime format and the use it in query

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($currentdatetime))
```

Also make sure database field is of data type datetime.

Comment: "$currentdatetime is my variable containing the current date and time in **'Y-m-d H:i:s'** format."