# Implement where condition varchar field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have usages table which contains field values like below

```
id | page_open_time

1, 28 May 2019 08:39:11
2, 12 July 2019 18:39:11
3, 22 December 2019 11:39:11
4, 23 June 2019 12:39:11
```

Now I would like to get all records where page_open_time is greater than 1 july, 2019. For this, I wrote this query below , but it didnt help. Is there any way, I can perform this ?

```
 SELECT * FROM `usages` where page_open_time > '2019-07-01'
```

Comment: Fix your data model so you are storing date/time values as `datetime` rather than as a string.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql Compare two datetime fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058031/mysql-compare-two-datetime-fields)

Comment: I got my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dates are not in a valid MySQL `DATETIME` format, so you need to convert them before comparison, using [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
SELECT *
FROM usages
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(page_open_time, '%d %M %Y %H:%i:%s') > '2019-07-01'
```

Output

```
id  page_open_time
2   12 July 2019 18:39:11
3   22 December 2019 11:39:11
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/okff1MBghLSvVT7JPMzMKB/0)